# How to wait in one request till another request finishes the execution of same function in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am using meteor. I have a route defined in iron router as follows,

```js
Router.route('/api/generatereceipt', {where: 'server'}).post(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("API: generatereceipt invoked.");
  const reqBody = req.body;
  ....
}
```

I want to generate a receipt one at a time. i.e. the receipt needs to have a unique number which is incremental in nature.

Right now I'm reading the previously stored receipt number and incrementing it by one. I consider that as the receipt number for currently processing receipt.

However, This works fine as long as the `generatereceipt` API is not called concurrently by multiple clients. When the API is called simultaneously, the same receipt number is considered for all the concurrently processed receipts.

Therefore I want to make a request check if the same REST API is called by some other client in some other request is under process. If it is in the process then I want to wait till its execution in that request thread finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue with concurrent requests. See the following example:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp'
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

// create a simple HTTP route

WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/api/generatereceipt', function (req, res, next) {
   // random 0 - 50ms timeout to simulate response delay
  const randomTimeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)

  // use Meteor's Promise.await to await async in non-async functions
  // --> should prevent troubles with legacy iron-router
  const receipt = Promise.await(getReceipt())
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.writeHead(200)
    res.end(String(receipt))
  }, randomTimeout)
})

// increment id and return new value
let receiptId = 0
async function getReceipt () {
  return receiptId++
}



Meteor.startup(function () {
  let testCount = 0
  const url = Meteor.absoluteUrl('/api/generatereceipt')

  // simulate concurrent calls by using a timeout of 0
  function call (id) {
    setTimeout(Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
      // simulate calling the /api/generatereceipt route
      const response = HTTP.get(url)
      console.log(id, ' => ', response.content) // should match
    }, 0))
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    call(testCount++)
  }
})
```

as you can see, the calls will resolve to the incremented ids:

```sh
=> Meteor server restarted                    
I20200703-09:59:15.911(2)? 9  =>  9
I20200703-09:59:15.912(2)? 7  =>  7
I20200703-09:59:15.913(2)? 4  =>  4
I20200703-09:59:15.913(2)? 0  =>  0
I20200703-09:59:15.913(2)? 21  =>  21
I20200703-09:59:15.913(2)? 24  =>  24
I20200703-09:59:15.913(2)? 17  =>  17
I20200703-09:59:15.913(2)? 18  =>  18
I20200703-09:59:15.915(2)? 2  =>  2
I20200703-09:59:15.917(2)? 19  =>  19
I20200703-09:59:15.923(2)? 6  =>  6
I20200703-09:59:15.923(2)? 23  =>  23
I20200703-09:59:15.925(2)? 11  =>  11
I20200703-09:59:15.928(2)? 8  =>  8
I20200703-09:59:15.931(2)? 16  =>  16
I20200703-09:59:15.932(2)? 10  =>  10
I20200703-09:59:15.934(2)? 5  =>  5
I20200703-09:59:15.934(2)? 13  =>  13
I20200703-09:59:15.934(2)? 22  =>  22
I20200703-09:59:15.936(2)? 20  =>  20
I20200703-09:59:15.936(2)? 15  =>  15
I20200703-09:59:15.939(2)? 14  =>  14
I20200703-09:59:15.940(2)? 1  =>  1
I20200703-09:59:15.940(2)? 3  =>  3
I20200703-09:59:15.943(2)? 12  =>  12
```

Comment: The solution which you have given works only when a same client makes concurrent requests. My requirement was to know the execution of the method from different request. For the same client i can even use Meteor's `this.unblock` for a method which will allow concurrent execution of methods. Anyway, thank you for showing a different way of making concurrent requests. Thank you.

Comment: `this.unblock` works only in Meteor methods using a DDP connected client, while iron router routes are HTTP based and there would be no `unblock` available.
There is also no real concurrency, since the node server is still single threated and all incoming requests are still processed in a single thread. I rather get the impression that you spawn multiple processes and run into the issue that each process has it's own counter. In such a case you will have to rely on a Mongo collection to persist to counter.

Comment: Ohh.. yes i never considered that i'm in iron router. `unblock` only works in a Meteor method. And as you are saying, we need to rely on a mongo collection to retain a global counter which can be seen by any process from any request. The npm package `mongodb-autoincrement` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this uses some kind of database/backend to store receipt ids? If so you should use constraints on your database to ensure that the receipt id is unique. Better yet, why not make the receipt id column an auto increment, then you don't need to check the previous receipt number and increment it yourself, it will be handled by the database layer and it just returned as part of the insert.

If it doesn't need to be auto incrementing, then just consider using a UUID.

I can't think of a single reason why you would want to wait on the execution. It would make your app slow for anyone other than the first request and would not be scalable.

If you really have a legitimate reason to structure it this way and generate the auto-increment yourself, then it would be better to explain in detail why this is the case as it might be there are better solutions then just "blocking" the next in line

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of doing the same but just thought whether we could check another request's execution. I would use `$inc` for mongo or autoValue from SimpleSchema by making it a unique field. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it's sorted, if this answer has helped you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Use async and await for waiting for completion of one request.

Comment: But async await works only in current thread. How to observe whether that API is running on other thread? or other request?